# Issue with "string type" format column in pgfplottable

Tags: pgfplotstable, strings, type

Using `pgfplotstable` library to define a table from a data file containing numeric and alphanumeric values, I get this error "! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'B' as a floating point number, "while compiling this short MWE example .. don't understand what's wrong with this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,makecell,booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    columns/0/.style={column name=\makecell{Col1\\{}},
        string type},
    columns/1/.style={column name=\makecell{Col2\\{}},
        column type=r,fixed},
    columns/2/.style={column name=\makecell{$GD$\\{}},
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    columns/3/.style={column name=\makecell{$\Delta$\\{}},
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
        after row={\midrule} % rule under units
    },
    skip first n=1
    ]
    {test_data.txt} % filename/path to file
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

`test_data.txt` file is:

```
Iter X Y Z
A 12.2 13.4 14.5
B 114.5 345.6 456.5
C 45 5 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The `skip first n` means that the first row of your data file is skipped, but because the first column has a non-numerical entry, the A-row is read as a header row with column names. When you have a table that has column names, you cannot use column indices when you set the column styles, i.e. `columns/<integer>/.style`. The manual says:

> If your tables don’t have column names, you can simply use integer indices instead of `<column name>` to refer to columns. If you have column names, you can’t set column styles using indices

Because you have column names, `column/0/.style` will influence the column with the *name* `0`, and *not* the index `0`. There is no such column, and as a result the first column does not get the `string type` key, and the `B` found there is parsed as a number. Which it is not.

Possible fixes:

- Add `header=false`. This means the A-row will not be parsed as a header row, and you can use indices to refer to the columns.
- Remove `skip first n=1`, and use `Iter`, `X`, `Y` and `Z` (i.e. the column names read from the first line) instead of the integer indices.
- Remove `skip first n=1` and use `display columns/<integer index>/.style` instead. (Display columns act on the output columns instead of input columns.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,makecell,booktabs}
\begin{document}

      \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    columns/0/.style={column name=\makecell{Col1\\{}},
        string type},
    columns/1/.style={column name=\makecell{Col2\\{}},
        column type=r,fixed},
    columns/2/.style={column name=\makecell{$GD$\\{}},
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    columns/3/.style={column name=\makecell{$\Delta$\\{}},
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
        after row={\midrule} % rule under units
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    header=false, % <---- add this
    skip first n=1
    ]
    {test_data.txt} 

\bigskip

      \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    columns/Iter/.style={column name=\makecell{Col1\\{}}, % <-- Iter
        string type},
    columns/X/.style={column name=\makecell{Col2\\{}}, % <-- X
        column type=r,fixed},
    columns/Y/.style={column name=\makecell{$GD$\\{}}, % <-- Y
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    columns/Z/.style={column name=\makecell{$\Delta$\\{}}, % <-- Z
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
        after row={\midrule} % rule under units
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
%    skip first n=1 % <-- remove
    ]
    {test_data.txt} 

\bigskip


      \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    display columns/0/.style={column name=\makecell{Col1\\{}}, % <-- display columns
        string type},
    display columns/1/.style={column name=\makecell{Col2\\{}}, % <-- display columns
        column type=r,fixed},
    display columns/2/.style={column name=\makecell{$GD$\\{}}, % <-- display columns
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    display columns/3/.style={column name=\makecell{$\Delta$\\{}}, % <-- display columns
        column type=r,sci,zerofill},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
        after row={\midrule} % rule under units
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    %skip first n=1 % <-- remove
    ]
    {test_data.txt} % filename/path to file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this totally accurate? In the section on `columns`, the `pgfplotstable` guide says "If your tables don’t have column names, you can simply use integer indices instead of <column name> to refer to columns. If you have column names, you can’t set column styles using indices." The `display columns` command is there so that you can refer to the column indices in the output table.

Comment: @StephenBosch I don't think I noticed that part, I suppose you're right that it's not entirely accurate.  In this case of course the table does have column names, so the last sentence of your quote applies.

Comment: @StephenBosch Thanks though, I completely rewrote my answer, as I realized I hadn't really understood what was going on. Should be better now.